# Issue with nodogsplash saying it needed updateed libmicrohttpd-dev, but I seems no new update have been updated?

Tags: server, raspberrypi

```
[5][Thu Feb 27 11:50:04 2020][1900](src/main.c:541) Starting as daemon, forking to background
[5][Thu Feb 27 11:50:04 2020][1901](src/main.c:254) MHD version is 0.9.62
[3][Thu Feb 27 11:50:04 2020][1901](src/main.c:270) libmicrohttpd is out of date, please upgrade to version 0.9.69 or higher
[3][Thu Feb 27 11:50:04 2020][1901](src/main.c:273) exiting...
```

I've have tried both upgrading nodogsplash and libmicrohttpd-dev but with failure. I can't find the updated versions for lib but I also tried for downgrading nodogsplash.

I've been following this guide.
https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-captive-portal/

Answer (score 0):

A quick dirty fix would be to go to `/nodogsplash/src/main.c` and replace the `MIN_MHD_PATCH` value with your version (in your case, 62) and make and install again.